# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 587

Tags: java, email, outlook, live

I've implemented a code that sends e-mails using Outlook server (worked fine locally).

What's the cause of the following exception on my production environment and how do I resolve it?

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 587; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

Comment: No other solution than to use a different SMTP server... Production environments are fun!

Comment: probably the production environment doesn't allow access to external sources.

Comment: Presumably the firewall blocks that access, you'll need to talk to someone in your organization (or your ISP's) NetOps team. Also, why did you tag this question "hotmail"?

Comment: @fge: I also tested with Gmail server and got the same result.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I'll check it. I tagged it as Hotmail because it's the old name of Outlook mail server.